# RegEx to move a decimal point to the second position of a string

Tags: regex, transform

I am try to move a decimal point in RegEx.   Example: 247.00 needs to be 2.470 (I had a typo, thanks Paul)  The decimal point will always be need to be the second character.

I am spinning my wheels and I have no idea.

Comment: What tool/programming language are you using?

Comment: This must be a typo: `247.00` should become `2.4700`, right?

Comment: Poorly described. Where is your regex that gives 247.00? Also it looks like you asking to change data using RegEx. RegEx is used to search data.

Comment: It is a software called Cleardox.  It allows me to pull data from all different types of sources and then normalize it for export into other systems.  I am pulling prices from a PDF and creating a price upload sheet for a commodity trading system.  The software using RegEx to Transform the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace matches of

```
(\d)(\d*)\.(\d+)(?<!00)0*
```

with

```
$1.$2$3
```

For example, the string `'247.200'` would become `'2.4720'`. The *negative lookbehind*, `(?<!00)`, prevents there being extra zeros at the end (`'2.47200'`), consistent with your example.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vlevPC/1)

---

If you want no trailing zeroes (`'2.472'`), except when there is only one digit to the right of the decimal (`'3.0'`), change the regex to:

```
(\d)(\d*)\.(\d+)(?<![^.]0)0*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/U6BLwL/1)

Answer (score -1):

Replace `(\d)(\d*)\.(\d*)` with `$1.$2$3`.

`\d` matches a digit. The first regular expression matches a digit, followed by any number of digits, followed by a decimal point, and then followed by any number of additional digits. The capture groups capture each of those groups of digits, then back-references are used in the replacement string to insert the `.` after the first digit.

In some languages the back-references are like `\1` instead of `$1`.